# QTreeWidgetItem.insertChild at index 0

Tags: python, pyside2, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am trying to insert a new child item at the top of the group of items. The index value does not seem to be honored and the item goes to the end of the list. I searched and did not find many hits for this type of operation in QTreeWidgets. I did find a simple program with which to experiment:

```
"""
simple test of treewidget
"""
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class Testclass():
    """
    test
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        test
        """
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)

        trw = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        trw.setHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Date', 'Cost ($)'])
        chg = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(trw, ['carrots', None, None])
        datrows = [[None, '2020-00-00', '0.33'],
                   [None, '2020-00-00', '0.35'],
                   [None, '2020-00-00', '0.36']]
        for datrow in datrows:
            __ = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, datrow)
        __ = chg.insertChild(0, QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, [None, '2020-00-00', '0.30']))


        layout.addWidget(trw)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

Testclass()
```

I played with changing the parent references in the tree widget item, changing the index. It added a blank item and then the new item at the end. The only what I got the desired effect was to fetch all the items, add the new item to the top of the list and rebuild the tree:

```
"""
simple test of treewidget
"""
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class Testclass():
    """
    test
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        test
        """
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)

        trw = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        trw.setHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Date', 'Cost ($)'])
        chg = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(trw, ['carrots', None, None])
        datrows = [[None, '2020-00-00', '0.33'],
                   [None, '2020-00-00', '0.35'],
                   [None, '2020-00-00', '0.36']]
        for datrow in datrows:
            __ = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, datrow)
        chi_list = []
        for chgiix, chgii in enumerate(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItemIterator(chg)):
            chg_item = chgii.value()
            if chgiix:
                coldata = []
                for colix in range(chg_item.columnCount()):
                    coldata.append(chg_item.text(colix))
                chi_list.append(coldata)
        chi_list.insert(0, [None, '2020-00-00', '0.30'])
        _ = trw.takeTopLevelItem(0)
        chg = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(trw, ['carrots', None, None])
        for datrow in chi_list:
            __ = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, datrow)
        print(chi_list)
        layout.addWidget(trw)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

Testclass()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong constructor, for example according to your code you are using [this constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#QTreeWidgetItem-6):

> **QTreeWidgetItem::QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem *parent, const
> QStringList &strings, int type = Type)**
>  Constructs a tree widget item
> and append it to the given parent. The given list of strings will be
> set as the item text for each column in the item.

That is, with `QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, [None, '2020-00-00', '0.30'])` you are already appending the item as a child of the "chg".

And then as the [`insertChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#insertChild) point out:

> **void QTreeWidgetItem::insertChild(int index, QTreeWidgetItem *child)**
> Inserts the child item at index in the list of children.
>
> **If the child has already been inserted somewhere else it won't be
> inserted again.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

That is, being the child of "chg" then it will not be inserted at the beginning.

The solution is not to pass "chg" but to use [this other constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#QTreeWidgetItem-1):

> **QTreeWidgetItem::QTreeWidgetItem(const QStringList &strings, int type =
> Type)**
>  Constructs a tree widget item of the specified type. The item
> must be inserted into a tree widget. The given list of strings will be
> set as the item text for each column in the item.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Testclass:
    def __init__(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)

        trw = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        trw.setHeaderLabels(["Name", "Date", "Cost ($)"])
        chg = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(trw, ["carrots", None, None])
        datrows = [
            [None, "2020-00-00", "0.33"],
            [None, "2020-00-00", "0.35"],
            [None, "2020-00-00", "0.36"],
        ]
        for datrow in datrows:
            QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(chg, datrow)
        chg.insertChild(0, QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([None, "2020-00-00", "0.30"]))

        layout.addWidget(trw)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


Testclass()
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not worked through all of the different constructors, had not considered them/